# How to show directories in vba's immediate window?

Tags: vba, directory, immediate-window

I want to list all directories in `c:` disk  in vba's immediate window,write the below code in immediate window:

```
Dim FileName As String
FileName = Dir("C:\", vbDirectory)

Do While FileName <> ""
    Debug.Print FileName
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
```

Now to click `enter`,

[image]

How to fix my vba code to show all directories in `c:` in vba's immediate window?

Comment: I ran your code and it worked just fine for me. I put it in a subroutine tho... did you try that? You cant just put all of that into the immediate window...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *immediate* window does not execute a script; it runs individual statements, *immediately* as you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (whether you just typed the line or not). You can't script a sequence of such executable statements in that box, the statements must be self-contained.

But you can cheat, by using the `:` *instruction separator*:

```
fn=dir("C:\",vbdirectory):do while fn<>"":?fn:fn=dir:loop
```

Keep in mind that the window holds no more than 255 lines - you'd have to write to a file to output more than that and be able to view it all.

Comment: You can, however, wrap the OP's code in a routine and execute from there, where `Debug.Print` will print to the immediate window. As I am sure you are aware...

Comment: @Dean OP was pretty clearly about using the immediate window though. Or maybe I misread, but I was under the impression OP was confused about how it works.